# WSO2 APIM 2.5 Deployment Patterns Pattern2

Tags: wso2

As per the documentation https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Deployment+Patterns#DeploymentPatterns-Pattern2 I am trying to setup WSO2 similar to Pattern 2. But from the documentation it is not quite clear what are the steps that needs to be followed.

Question:
 1. How can I start Store, Publisher and Traffic Manager on same server?
Do I have to start them in single startup script or start them independently? When I try starting them independently I see there are conflicts. How to resolve those conflicts?

Regards,
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

> Question: 1. How can I start Store, Publisher and Traffic Manager on same server? Do I have to start them in single startup script or start them independently?

If you start the default WSO2 API Manager (without any [profile parameter](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Product+Profiles)), it starts the "all-in-one" mode. This mode contains all features (store, publisher, key maanger, gateway, traffic manaager, ..). You don't have to do anything with it.

For the key manager and gateway, you should specify the profile parameter which should disable some non-essential feature for the specified profile.

Comment: Hi Gusto,
Thank you for you response. I got your point but if the Gateway & Key Manager are running on a separate server, why would we run duplicate? Wouldn't it be wise not to start "all-in-one" and start only Store, Publisher and Traffic Mgr instead?
Also, what if I want to run Gateway and Key Manager together on one server? (which is my desired configuration)

Thanks,
Deepak

Comment: @deepak You would have duplicates, but it doesn't matter. You cannot set like *start all except gateway* or combine any profiles together. You either have all in one or a specific profile selected. See the linked page for possible profiles. IMHO you can use the main (all-in-one) node as a key manager and have the gateways separater for security and scaling purposes.

Comment: I was reading several blogs trying to get my understanding right. In one of the blogs(link below) Chanaka Fernando, Associate Director @ WSO2 writes "... you can think of keeping both Gateway and Key Manager nodes combined into one JVM ..."
I guess there is a way to turn of selected components while starting all-in-one. Its just that it isn't documented and known only to WSO2 engineers internally

https://medium.com/@chanakaudaya/understanding-wso2-api-manager-deployment-patterns-6faac8548f8d

Comment: I was able run Key Manager, Store and Publisher individually on a single server (Please refer to link: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Changing+the+Default+Ports+with+Offset)

However, now I have 3 Management Consoles running on 3 different ports on the same server :)  Need to figure out how to fix it!